# How do I make a Fragment cast a shadow on its host Activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'd like something like the image below. The fragment appears over part of the host activity and the fragment should cast a shadow over the activity. I've tried setting the elevation of the fragment's layout root view and of the view that hosts the fragment in the activity layout.

[image]

Comment: Add a semitransparent background (9 patch?) to an ImageView on top of the green area.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a CardView and set its elevation to give it a shadow.

Answer (score 0):

try the same trick again but this time just give margin to the root element in fragment's layout, and for a clear shadow keep the margin greater then its elevation.

Answer (score 0):

A few years late but try playing with this.

```
ViewCompat.setTranslationZ(view, 5)
```